# Call axios on server, but latter on page and not fetch or asyncData on start

Tags: cors, axios, nuxt.js

I have simple nuxt page that pulls data with `fetch` from server (axios) to populate the table for initial load, that works great.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import CONST from '@/store/settings.js'
import mix from '@/components/mymixin'

export default {
  mixins: [ mix ],
  data() {
    return {
      msg: new Date(),
      domains: [],
      fields: [{
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Domain',
        sortable: true
      },{
        key: 'status', 
        label: 'Status'
      },{
        key: 'development_mode',
        label: 'Bypass CF',
        formatter: value => (value != '0') ? true : false, 
        sortable: true
      },{
        key: 'paused',
        label: 'Paused', 
        sortable: true
      },{
        key: 'actPageRules',
        label: 'Page Rules'
      }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    info ( item, ix ) {
      axios.get( `${CONST.base}/zones/${item.id}/pagerules`, { headers: CONST.headers })
      .then( (res) => { console.log( res.data ) })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    var me = this
    setInterval(function(){
      me.msg = new Date()
    }, 1000 )
    this.domains = this.$store.state.domains
  },
  fetch ( { store, params  } ) {
    const domains   = store.$axios.get( `${CONST.base}/zones?per_page=${CONST.pg}&account.id=${CONST.uid}`, { headers: CONST.headers })
      .then( (res) => { store.state.domains = res.data.result })
    // const registrar = axios.get( `${CONST.base}/accounts/${CONST.uid}/registrar/domains`, { headers: CONST.headers })
    //   .then( (res) => { this.domains = store.state.registrar = res.data.result })
    return Promise.all([ domains ])
  }, 
  asyncData( { store, params } ){

  }
}
```

my table template is this

```
<b-table class="table-responsive" striped hover :fields="fields" :items="domains">

  <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
    <a :href="`#${data.value}`">{{ data.value }}</a>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:cell(development_mode)="data">
    <b-form-checkbox v-model="data.value" name="devmode" switch />
  </template>

  <template v-slot:cell(paused)="data">
    <b-form-checkbox v-model="data.value" name="paused" switch/>
  </template>

  <template v-slot:cell(actPageRules)="data">
    <b-button size="sm" @click="info(data.item)" class="mr-1" variant="warning">
      Page Rules
    </b-button>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

and table renders correctly. Now, I'd like to trigger, with `info` method `axios.get` on server!

The error that I get is that because of CORS I can't run that it on client ..

[image]

So my question is, how to trigger (via click or anyhow) method to run on server and not on client?

much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

after alot of google-ing with strnge keywords I got it

-- to other Googlers who stumbleupon here ,, to be able to prevent CORS errors and have server request to some remote API's (in my case it was CloudFlare and MailChimp + Godaddy for DNS) , we have to **proxy** our requests via our server!

This page have all details of putting and building it up on our own >

https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options